# Firebase Database is Declining Requests

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

Firebase Realtime Data base is declining my requests and I  don't know why?
[See This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1qKL.png)
I have used just simple code from documentation.
This is HTML page.

```js
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.23.0/firebase-app.js"></script>

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.23.0/firebase-analytics.js"></script>

<script>
  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "xxxxxxxxx",
    authDomain: "app.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://app.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "app",
    storageBucket: "jointest-jic.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxx",
    appId: "x:xxxxx4:web:xxxxxxx",
    measurementId: "xcxvcxv"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  firebase.analytics();
  var database = firebase.database();
  function writeUserData(userId, name, email, imageUrl) {
  firebase.database().ref('users/' + userId).set({
    username: name,
    email: email,
    profile_picture : imageUrl
  });
}
</script>
```

```html
<body>
<input type="submit" onclick="writeUserData(userId, name, email, ageUrl)">
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not forget to import scripts for all components that you will use like `<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.23.0/firebase-database.js"></script>` for using realtime database =))

Also you need to properly configure database rules for your database either in the firebase web console
[image]

or in your firebase.json file, as you can read [here.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/get-started)

Comment: firebase database is not a function.>>>Uncaught TypeError: firebase.database is not a function
    at writeUserData (ftp.html:26)
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (ftp.html:1)

Comment: you can try to investigate the `Cloud Monitoring` tool for some events or incidents, the link should be on the monitore rules page

Comment: @VedNig for some reason it cant initialize your firebase

Comment: what can it be? i saw that too but it is empty.

Comment: add `<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.23.0/firebase-database.js"></script>` to your imports

Comment: that worked thank you, pls. update anwer(if you want...:-)

Comment: and please guide me for scripting database rules.I don't know where to go

Comment: updated thanks=) and for database rules you can find all options in the documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/rules-conditions

Comment: and here is good article https://medium.com/@juliomacr/10-firebase-realtime-database-rule-templates-d4894a118a98